# How to use C++ 20 in g++

Tags: c++, g++, c++20

I am trying to access `std::popcount`, but it seems like it's [only there in C++ 20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount#:%7E:text=since%20C++20).

When I try compiling with `g++ -std=c++20 main.cpp`, it says `g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++20'; did you mean '-std=c++03'`

How do I tell g++ to use c++ 20?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Your version of `g++` is too old. You need at least 9+ for `popcount` (and that would be `-std=c++2a`) or 10+ to be able to actually write `c++20`.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? Does it [include C++20 support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)?

Comment: Important: Because the ISO C++20 standard is very recent, GCC's support is experimental. https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20

Comment: also if you use g++-9 and cmake. try  `set(CMAKE_CXX20_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION  "-std=c++2a")
set(CMAKE_CXX20_EXTENSION_COMPILE_OPTION  "-std=gnu++2a")` in CMakeLists

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would try updating gcc. C++ 20 was introduced in gcc version 8 which is pretty new.

Answer (score 65):

C++20 features are available since GCC 8.

To enable C++20 support, add the command-line parameter

> `-std=c++20`

For G++ 9 and earlier use

> `-std=c++2a`

Or, to enable GNU extensions in addition to C++20 features, add

> `-std=gnu++20`

Comment: There is also `-std=gnu++2a`

Comment: "For G++ 9 and later" should be "For G++ 9 and earlier".

Answer (score 7):

If it's an option you can update to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which includes GCC version 9 out of the box. This would enable you to use C++ 20 and thus `std::popcount`

Note: use `-std=c++2a` in GCC 9 and earlier

Answer (score 1):

there are different versions of the compiler exist and `g++` is usually linked to the older one. for me, the current one is `g++-9` and it clearly does not understand C++20.

C++20 requires installing `gcc-10` and `g++-10` (plus dependencies). assuming you already have them installed, then you need to run:

```
g++-10 -std=c++20 main.cpp
```

PS: if you want to go with v10 as default, then update links for `gcc`, `g++` and other related ones, and use v9 (or whatever old you have) by full name.

EDIT: depending on the host OS, v11 and v12 could also be installed, but the naming is still important. replace with `g++-11` or `g++-12`.